# How to return data based on promise

Tags: ember.js, concurrency

I have a "virtual attribute" in a model, and I want the setter to wait for the promise before returning the value :

```
idShop:Ember.computed('shop',function(){
    get(key){
      return this.get('shop').id;
    },
    set(k,v){
      this.get('store').findRecord('shop',key)
      .then(shop =>{ 
        this.set('shop', shop)
      })
    }
  })
```

In the set, I need to return either k(key) or shop.id after `findRecord` and it's `then` are solved. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried to use the async/await pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perspective this is a big red flag. I would not use the setter in this case because it depends on an async task to complete. The two options I see are:

1. redesign the computed property to use `PromiseProxyMixin` objects. (This would overly complicate the situation and I would not recommend in this case)
2. Drop the use of a setter all together. Make the property readOnly and add a method you call to set it which can return a promise.

I would be easier to reason about if you sent an model to that property instead of a key. If this is a problem because your sticking to a two-way bound input helper then look into a DDAU version of that selector so that it calls an action instead of sets a property. Or wrap this in a component that knows how to convert a key into a model and then set the model on the relationship after it has resolved.

I think @donald-wasserman was suggesting the later with his [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/) example. However, it isn't required in your case. It would provide some benefits (cancellation) but I wouldn't get caught up in the ember-concurrency part of the solution but in the design on how and where you're performing the async lookup.

Async dependencies are much easier to reason about when they are performed as an action and not as side-effects of computed properties. CP are not really meant for async things. I know that in some cases one can get away with it using a proxy (i.e. ember-data) but it does introduce a level of cognitive load that can quickly get out of hand. **Default to actions for async needs.**

For a vanilla select you would have to have a translation layer (hence component) that can convert the string key to a model lookup. Some select addons will do this for you (for example [ember-power-select](http://ember-power-select.com/)) The lookup translation is the responsibility of a component not a model which is probably why you've run into difficulties.

Regarding adding a method to the model to perform the async lookup: you can do this but I would argue it is probably a poor design choice as it mixes/blurs the line of responsibilities. (i.e. [Single Responsibility Principle of S.O.L.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

In other words the needs of the select is a presentation concern. The fact that there is need to convert a string (for presentation logic) to a model (for business logic) really isn't the model's responsibility. The model should be responsible to just store the relationship. It is the component that renders the select that is responsible for converting models to and from a format appropriate for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a great use case for [Ember Concurrency.](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/introduction/)

Ember concurrency (EC) uses generator functions `function * () {}` inside of it's `task()` method to make it easier to manage things like this. A task also provides a few utility properties to show if it's currently `running` or `idle` (aka loading data, or done loading data).

Here's how I'd set this up (code for ember 2.17 and later)

```
import {task} from 'ember-concurrency';
import {computed} from '@ember/object';
# skip ahead to later in the code...
shop: null,
loadShop: task(function*(key) {
   let shop = yield this.get('store').findRecord('shop', key)
   this.set('shop', shop)
}),
shopId: computed('shop', function() {
  if (this.get('shop') {
    return this.get('shop.id);
  } else {
     return null;
  }
})
```

Depending on your exact use case, you'd call `this.get('loadShop').perform(id)` when you knew what the id would be (likely in an in init hook or in a separate method)

(Note: it's a bad practice to mutate properties as part of a computed property. Computed properties really should be stateless.)